# Pinecone ApiException: (400) Reason: Bad Request for Generative QA with OpenAI

Tags: openai-api, huggingface-datasets, pinecone

I am following the Pinecone user guide to use [Generative QA with OpenAI](https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/gen-qa-openai).

After having downloaded the dataset and having created a new merged dataset, I rand the following code:

```
# check if index already exists (it shouldn't if this is first time)
if index_name not in pinecone.list_indexes():
    # if does not exist, create index
    pinecone.create_index(
        index_name,
        dimension=len(res['data'][0]['embedding']),
        metric='cosine',
        metadata_config={'indexed': ['channel_id', 'published']}
    )
# connect to index
index = pinecone.GRPCIndex(index_name)
# view index stats
index.describe_index_stats()
```

Which results in the following error:

```
if index_name not in pinecone.list_indexes():
    # if does not exist, create index
    pinecone.create_index(
        index_name,
        dimension=128,
        metric='cosine',
        metadata_config={'indexed': ['channel_id', 'published']}
    )
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[61], line 3
    pinecone.create_index(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\manage.py:118 in create_index
    api_instance.create_index(create_request=CreateRequest(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:776 in __call__
    return self.callable(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api\index_operations_api.py:370 in __create_index
    return self.call_with_http_info(**kwargs)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:838 in call_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:413 in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:207 in __call_api
    raise e

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:200 in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:459 in request
    return self.rest_client.POST(url,

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\rest.py:271 in POST
    return self.request("POST", url,

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\rest.py:230 in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)

ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Mon, 03 Jul 2023 19:47:24 GMT', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '1133', 'content-length': '131', 'server': 'envoy'})
HTTP response body: The index exceeds the project quota of 1 pods by 1 pods. Upgrade your account or change the project settings to increase the quota.
```

The message seems clear, namely that I need to upgrade my account. On [the information page  about indexes](https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/indexes), it states that the starter plan allows for approximately 100,000 vectors with 1536-dimensional embeddings and metadata. `data` consists of 208619 of such embeddings + metadata. So, the ApiException makes sense.

However, when I change the dimension size it still returns the `ApiException` error.

```
if index_name not in pinecone.list_indexes():
    # if does not exist, create index
    pinecone.create_index(
        index_name,
        dimension=186,
        metric='cosine',
        metadata_config={'indexed': ['channel_id', 'published']}
    )
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[64], line 3
    pinecone.create_index(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\manage.py:118 in create_index
    api_instance.create_index(create_request=CreateRequest(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:776 in __call__
    return self.callable(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api\index_operations_api.py:370 in __create_index
    return self.call_with_http_info(**kwargs)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:838 in call_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:413 in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:207 in __call_api
    raise e

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:200 in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py:459 in request
    return self.rest_client.POST(url,

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\rest.py:271 in POST
    return self.request("POST", url,

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\wlh\lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\rest.py:230 in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)

ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Mon, 03 Jul 2023 20:09:01 GMT', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '1114', 'content-length': '131', 'server': 'envoy'})
HTTP response body: The index exceeds the project quota of 1 pods by 1 pods. Upgrade your account or change the project settings to increase the quota.
```

Does the error indeed imply that I need to upgrade to a paid plan, or can I resolve this differently too?

Answer (score 0):

PineCone provides for ONLY 1 Index to be created with the starter GCP free plan. Your Index may already have been created and create_index code is running again to create one. use pinecone_client.Index("INDEX_NAME") to get the created index and work with it.